# In Java Is it possible to convert character set 1047 into another character set, say 500?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a program which reads a message from MQ. the character set is 1047. Since my java version is very old it doesn't support thus character set.

Is it possible to change this string into char set 500 in the program after receiving but before reading.

For eg:

```
public void fun (String str){         //str in char set 1047. **1047 is not supported in my system**
  /* can I convert str into char set 500 here. Convert it into byte stream and then back to      string. Something like this */

             byte [] b=str.getBytes();
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
       try{
         baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         baos.write(b);
         String str = baos.toString("IBM-500");
         System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

byte [] b=str.getBytes(); //will convert string(encoding could only be Unicode in jvm) to bytes using file.encoding. You should check whether the str contains correct information, if so, you need not care the 1047 encoding, just run str.getBytes("IBM-500"), you will get the 500 encoded bytes. Again, String object only use Unicode, if you convert string to bytes, the encoding matters the result bytes array.